# How can I find the closest location on a map to an arbitrary point?

Tags: c++

**Note:** For the remainder of this question I will call this arbitrary point as  "myPoint" to avoid confusion.

**Problem:** There are several points on the map (it not practical to calculate the distance between each point and myPoint).

**Attempt at a Solution:** I tried doing a radius search but in order to know where these points are located within the circle, I would have to go through all the points and make sure the distance between them is less than the search circle's radius.

**Question:** How can I find the closest point to myPoint in an efficient way? Please ask questions if clarification is needed.

Comment: it kind of depends on how you are doing these points... You can use some vector algebra and if you know the dimensions then you should be able to subtract your location from the point.

Comment: these points are latitude/longitude, I have a database that has each points' coordinates

Comment: I'm assuming the points are (x,y) coordinates? Are keeping them in some kind of ordered/sorted list? If so and you did something like a binary search you wouldn't be calculating the distance between each point.

Comment: If the points are in a database, does the engine have built in functions for spatial calculations? Most databases implement some part of the OpenGIS standards which are for the type of data you're dealing with.

Comment: We don't know what myPoint is before the program is run, therefrore we cannot store the distances in a list.

Comment: No, we don't have any built-in functions for spatial calculations

Comment: @ConfusedCoder well it seems like you need to make some kind of grid "map" of (x,y) "latitude/longitude" plot your points then maybe a radar like search that grows larger each pass from your stationary point...

Comment: Why can't you employ the _O(n log n)_ solution described here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) (possibly the _dynamic closest-pair problem_ is more applicable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a technique to "partition" the search space (i.e., the map).

You could consider defining a regular grid that covers the map and store all map locations within each cell of the grid.

With this it is easy to calculate/determine which cell contains the *myPoint*. Then it is just a matter of considering the points within the same cell.

Note: You may have to consider neighboring cells too in the event the cell containing *myPoint* doesn't have any map locations or that the distance to a point in a neighboring cell is shorter than the distance to the point within the same cell (e.g., *myPoint* is near a cell border).

Comment: what if the CLOSEST point is in a different box, but using your algorithm, you would never find this point as you are restrciting yourself to only the box that you are in

Comment: @ConfusedCoder It's funny that you mention that, I was in the middle of editing my solution to mention this case.

Comment: You provided the best answer but I decided to go with a KD-tree

Comment: @ConfusedCoder Ah yes, a KD-tree sounds like a viable solution as well. Did you also consider a quad tree solution?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the distance between the points is inevitable. What I suggest you can do is to slice the map in smaller pieces (not necessarily regular) and then only calculate the distance between the points that lie in the same slice.